# Android Studio windows 11 - where is JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, android-studio, path

Using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 and trying to run this command in Bash termimal:

```
$ ./gradlew signingReport
```

and get this response:

```
    ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java.exe
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
    location of your Java installation.
```

Having checked similar questions have set the `JAVA_HOME` 3 different ways:

(1) using `$ nano ~/.bashrc` and setting is as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java.exe"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

(2) running this in Bash command prompt:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java.exe"
```

(3) Through the Control Panel:

- Navigate to "System and Security" -> "System" -> "Advanced system settings".
- In the System Properties dialog, go to the "Advanced" tab.
- Click the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom.
- In the "Environment Variables" dialog, under "System variables", click the "New" button.
- Set the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
- Set the variable value as `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java.exe`

Still, when I run `$ echo %JAVA_HOME%` I just get `%JAVA_HOME%`

I've tried going into Android Studio looking for the path under: `File`->`Project Structure`->`SDK Location`->`Gradle Settings`->`Gradle JDK` and copying the path `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr` and substituted this path into the steps above all with the same outcome.

I have not loaded Java separately as I've been running/creating java apps with my version for Android Studio for many months.

Comment: `...\java.exe` (usually) is a file, not a directory! I would try `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr` (assuming `jbr` is the directory the JDK is installed in) || Also caution with backslashes - these are for Windows/DOS; Unix/bash uses forward slash as directory separator (better set the variables in Windows, usually they are correctly converted in bash)|| BTW `%JAVA_HOME%` does not work in bash, only DOS/WIndows; use `$JAVA_HOME`

Comment: YES!  That got be going correctly and I was able to set the path variable and successfully run the `$ ./gradlew signingReport` command.  You solved this @user16320675 so please post your response separately and I will mark this as resolved.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT my answer but from @user16320675:

`...\java.exe` (usually) is a file, not a directory! I would try `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr` (assuming jbr is the directory the JDK is installed in) || Also caution with backslashes - these are for Windows/DOS; Unix/bash uses forward slash as directory separator (better set the variables in Windows, usually they are correctly converted in bash)|| BTW `%JAVA_HOME%` does not work in bash, only DOS/WIndows; use `$JAVA_HOME`